# Когда нужно использовать Service?

Tags: android

В каких случаях в `android` разработке нужно использовать `Service`?

Answer (score 4):

`Service` является компонентом приложения, который может выполнять длительные операции в фоновом режиме и не содержит пользовательского интерфейса. Другой компонент приложения может запустить службу, которая продолжит работу в фоновом режиме даже в том случае, когда пользователь перейдет в другое приложение. Кроме того, компонент может привязаться к службе для взаимодействия с ней и даже выполнять межпроцессное взаимодействие (IPC). Например, служба может обрабатывать сетевые транзакции, воспроизводить музыку, выполнять ввод-вывод файла или взаимодействовать с поставщиком контента, и все это в фоновом режиме.

[Источник](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html?hl=ru)

Answer (score 3):

Итак, сервис – это некая задача, которая работает в фоне и не использует UI. Запускать и останавливать сервис можно из приложений и других сервисов. Также можно подключиться к уже работающему сервису и взаимодействовать с ним.

Т.е. сервис нужен, чтобы ваша задача продолжала работать, даже когда приложение закрыто.

Answer (score 2):

Про случаи, в которых нужно использовать сервисы, хорошо сказано [тут](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/services-theory.php):

> Сервисы предназначены для длительного существования, в отличие от
>   активностей. Они могут работать, постоянно перезапускаясь, выполняя
>   постоянные задачи или выполняя задачи, требующие много времени.
>
> ...
>
> Службы идеально подходят для проведения постоянных или регулярных
>   операций, а также для обработки событий даже тогда, когда активности
>   вашего приложения невидимы, работают в пассивном режиме или закрыты.
>
> ...
>
> Если ваше приложение выполняет задачи, которые не зависят от прямого
>   взаимодействия с пользователем, сервисы могут стать хорошим выбором.
>
> ...
>
> Приложения, которые регулярно обновляются, но очень редко или
>   нерегулярно взаимодействуют с пользователем, можно назвать первыми
>   кандидатами на реализацию в виде сервисов. Проигрыватели MP3 и
>   приложения, отслеживающие спортивные результаты, — примеры программ,
>   которые должны постоянно работать и обновляться без необходимости
>   отображать активность.